# Manage localhost ports when developing with Visual Studio with several users on one machine

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express

In our Visual Studio development (VS2015), we share one virtualized machine with several developers. We had to solve several minor problems with this setup but discovered a more annoying problem now.

Our solution consists of a client that uses web services, that are implemented in a ASP.NET project. When we start our client, we also start the services so that the calls can be made from the client. The services get started on the localhost port that is entered in the project properties. But when we work with several developers we have the problem that Visual Studio would use the same port for all developers and as we are on the same machine, the web project will not start because the port is already used. We now have following questions:

We can separate the ports by editing the IIS config file but we also have to change the port in the client and after each checkin all developers again have the same port.

1) Is there a clever way to manage the ports in the local IIS express?

2) How can we configure the ports in the clients so that the configuration is not overwritten by each checkin of other developers?

Comment: You could use Docker for running your application. Or have a script that configures your application for running locally. Or stop developing on the same machine.

Comment: We have no free choice about charing the machine and Docker seems to be the wrong solution for starting the application for debugging. But the script idea is worth a try. But: Is there no VS way to solve the issue?

Comment: Most Visual Studio users should have their dedicate machines to use, instead of sharing with others, so we can see the current design of VS follows such assumption. You would have to do some manual work in that case, and I doubt Microsoft would ever consider to give better support.